# How to get facebook image

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

Using the Graph API I get the url for an Image of a person. Now I would like to save that Image to a device, save where I have saved that image to and SQL database and then call from that sql the picture directory and set it to an Imageview,

How should I do that?

(I have been looking for tutorials, but could not find any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the url into database. Before showing the image to imageView, get the url from database and show to imageview using [Picasso Library](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Comment: But the URL is not working. How can I fix that (when loading with Picasso it just gives me a blank image, but if I inser any other link, it works fine)

Comment: can you share the link.

Answer (score 0):

One you have the Image URL, you need to do an HTTP GET on the URL.

Just start an `AsyncTask` and use a `HttpURLConnection` to download the image from the URL.